# how can i add watermark and compress a batch of video with ffmpeg

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, watermark

i am using ffmpeg for video editing

i am adding watermark to a bulk of videos with

for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex "overlay=1000:10" -preset slow -codec:a copy "newfiles%%~na.mp4"

now i want to merge

for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset faster -tune film  "newfiles%%~na.mp4"

so it will add watermark and compress the size of the videos

is there any way to merge them ?????

Answer (score 0):

Merged command:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex "overlay=1000:10"  -crf 28 -preset faster -tune film -codec:a copy "newfiles%%~na.mp4"
```